# React.js - how do I call a setState function after another one has finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I must be missing something obvious here. I have a to-do list app which uses a function for creating new lists. Once `createList` is called I want to then highlight the list by setting its `selected` prop to `true` So below are the two methods for doing this. I'm trying to call one after the other. Both of them modify state using the appropriate callback that uses `prevState`, yet for whatever reason `createList` does not set the new list in state before `toggleSelected` gets called, and so `listName` is undefined in `toggleSelected`. Is there anyway to ensure the new list object is set in state before calling `toggleSelected`? I should probably be using Redux but I didn't want to get into it for my first React app.

```
createList = (listName) => {
  const lists = {...this.state.lists};
  lists[listName] = {
    listName: listName,
    selected: false,
    todos: {}
  };

  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {lists: prevState.lists};
  });
};

toggleSelected = (listName) => {
    let selected = this.state.lists[listName].selected;
    selected = !selected;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        bookLists: update(prevState.lists, {[listName]: {selected: {$set: selected}}})
      };
    });
};
```

Both methods are called in another component like so after an `onSubmit` handler with the new list name being passed in:

```
this.props.createList(newListName);
this.props.toggleSelected(newListName);
```

PS - If you're wondering what's up with `update()`, it's from an immutability-helper plugin that allows for easily setting nested values in a state object(in this case, `state.lists[listName].selected`)--another reason I probably should have gone with Redux.

PPS - I realize I can just set the new list's `selected` prop to `true` from the start in `creatList` but there's more to the app and I need to set it after creation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do what you're doing in `toggleSelected` right now, instead toggle the `selected` flag in your list (without extracting it) and then let your component know you updated the `lists` data by rebinding the resulting object:

```
class YourComponent {
  ...
  toggleSelected(listName) {
    let lists = this.state.lists;
    let list = lists[listName];
    list.selected = !list.selected;
    this.setState({ lists });
  }
  ..
}
```

Then make sure that in your render function, where you create the UI for each list, you check whether `selected` is true or false so you can set the appropriate `classNames` string.

(Also note that in your code, you used `selected = !selected`. That isn't going to do much, because you *extracted* a boolean value, flipped it, and then didn't save it back to where it can be consulted by other code)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Quick question: what do you mean `toggleSelected` is generating components? From what I see, it's just updating state with the flipped `selected` (this method has been working as expected in other parts of the app).

Comment: I might have misread what your setState did, you're not passing it a state and a callback, but only a function (which may be a new way setState is to be called, all the code I've worked with so far is `this.setState(stateobj, callbackwhenupdated)`).

Comment: Ah, nope. The first argument to `setState` can be an updater function with the following signature `(prevState, props) => stateChange`. From what I understand, this is the correct way to update state: since setState is asnyc, `prevState` will return state after any other methods alter it.

Comment: It's the correct way to call it for code that would be a problem otherwise (like a counter that naively relies on a value from this.state). This code doesn't suffer from that (due to the explicit edits on list name) so we can use the "just pass the new state" update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the second setState function. It is at the first line of the toggleSelected() method.

When the toggleSelected() method is executed, the first setState haven't been executed.

The flow of the your code is:

1. createList();
2. toggleSelected();
3. setState() in createList();
4. setState() in toggleSelected();

Solution 1:
Use **await** and **async** keywords

Solution 2: 
Use redux